# Ubuntu Logo is not appearing during boot and shutdown

Tags: logo

Ubuntu is cool but not if you don’t know what went wrong. Recently I made some changes which caused the Ubuntu logo to disappear (*Symbol with circle animation*). The logo doesn’t appear anymore while booting or shutting down. The only thing which appear on booting and shutdown is **4 dots** which change color (*red & white*).

I have no idea of what I possibly could have done wrong.

Here are my questions:

What is the main reason of such problem?
Can I undo the changes and put the logo back?

Comment: What kind of changes did you made? and which tool did u use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

Here is what i did, if anyone out there having the same problem.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Then reboot